# Switched website hosting, only some domain users can see site

Tags: dns, website, windows-domain, domain-name

We have switched hosting companies after redesigning our site. I have changed the domain IP in the DNS manager to the new domain. This worked until the old site with the old host was terminated. After that some users within our domain cannot see the site (all can see outside the domain). I tried updating group policies on the user that can't see with no success.

Where those users somehow viewing the new site through the old domain hosting when it was still active? How do I correct this?

Comment: Have the DNS servers those computers are set to use been updated with the new sites' IP address?  Have you tried flushing the DNS cache on the problematic machines?  What happens if they try to access the new site via its IP address?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 You can't necessarily access web sites by their IP addresses anymore, due to virtual hosting. Your browser won't know how to correctly fill in the SNI field of the TLS handshake or the mandatory "Host:" header in HTTP. So the server won't know which of its virtually hosted websites it should serve to you when you connect by IP address.

Comment: DNS server has been set to the IP address. I have tried flushing the DNS cache and temp files. Also tried a gpudate and reboot.

Comment: if you do a `tracert` to the domain, does it hit the expected IP address?

Comment: Thank you. This was resolved by adding the SSL cert to the ADFS server.